# How to push new element to an array created in JavaScript global variable in another .js file?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a variable containing two arrays :

```
var x={ arr1:[] , arr2:[]};
```

I want to push new element to `arr1`, I try this but the word "push" does not appear as an option:

```
(x.arr1).push("hi");
```

and

```
x.arr1.push("hi");
```

***EDIT***

I'm really sorry , that thing above actually works , I thought it is the same as if the variable `x` was global var defined in another `js` file,I am new to JS . 
So now let me explain more , x is a global variable defined in `client.js` file and there I set it with some properties, now I want to add more properties to it but from another `js` file called : `server.js` ,so I add these arrays to it as I mentioned above and when trying to push elements then it does not automatically completes the word "push".

`client.js`:

```
var gl={id: '123' , 
        myfunc: function(){console.log("client func");}
       };
```

`server.js`:

```
gl.arr1=[]; 
gl.arr1.push("hi");  //this does not work,it is like gl forgot about arr1
```

Sorry again..

Comment: You don't show the whole picture in your question. The way it's written, the first array is accessed correctly (in both cases, though parentheses are redundant), so any correct autocomplete system should work.

Comment: You could try x.arr1.append["Hi"]

Comment: Then something else is wrong; works fine. `{arr1: Array(2), arr2: Array(0)}
arr1
:
(2) ["hi", "hi"]
arr2
:
[]` What do you mean by "doesn't appear as an option"? Object introspection only goes so far.

Answer (score 1):

why not define it in the first place in client.js like this:

```
var gl={id: '123' , 
        myfunc: function(){console.log("client func");} , 
        arr1 : [] ,
        arr2 : []
       };
```

and in server.js use it as you mentioned above :

```
 gl.arr1.push("hi");
```

Comment: because there might be more than tab/browser connected to the same server , in my case , chat application , for example if one user logged in after that some other users who already logged in and already have messages between each other , I want also for the new user to see the conversation from the beginning even before he logged

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x['arr1'].push('Hello')
```

Hope it Helps. Cheers!

Comment: No different than `x.arr1` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = { arr1: [], arr2: [] };

x.arr1.push("hi");

console.log(x);
```

That's one way how it's done, what do you mean with "an option", you should try your snippets in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io)